# Capybara Select2 Help w/Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara

For some reason im running into problems with Select2 and Firefox w/Geckodriver.

Select2 fields I used to be able to just say `page.select 'Text', from: 'Label'` however that no longer works I just get a `Element <option> could not be scrolled into view` (Despite being scrolled into view). Right now im doing something similar to this:

```
  select2Fields = page.all('.select2-selection')
  select2Fields[0].click
  page.find('.select2-search__field').set('Text To Set')
  within('.select2-results') do
    page.find('li', text: 'Text To Click').click
  end
```

It's ugly and doesn't fit with my Page Object Model method, since I have to sorta know which select2 field it is. It doesn't seem to be when finding it with a label.

Any ideas? It's very frustrating since it worked with Chrome but the latest chromedriver has issues with the newest capybara versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you were using that you were able to ever use `select` with a select2 widget, it never should have worked, and the fact it did would have been a bug.  The reason is the actual `<select>` element (which is what Capybaras `select` method works with) is non-visible on the page, and `select2` replaces it with a JS driven widget.  You need to do exactly what a user would do, which is click to make the widget show up then click on the `<li>` element which represents the correct entry. This can all be moved into a helper method and potentially some custom selectors which boils down to something like this

```
Capybara.add_selector(:select2) do
  xpath do |locator, **options|
    xpath = XPath.descendant(:select)
    xpath = locate_field(xpath, locator, options)
    xpath = xpath.next_sibling(:span)[XPath.attr(:class).contains_word('select2')][XPath.attr(:class).contains_word('select2-container')]
    xpath
  end
end

Capybara.add_selector(:select2_option) do
  xpath do |locator|
    # Use anywhere to escape from the current scope since select2 appends
    # the choices to the end of the document
    xpath = XPath.anywhere(:ul)[XPath.attr(:class).contains_word('select2-results__options')][XPath.attr(:id)]
    xpath = xpath.descendant(:li)[XPath.attr(:role) == 'treeitem']
    xpath = xpath[XPath.string.n.is(locator.to_s)] unless locator.nil?
    xpath
  end
end

def select_from_select2(value, from: nil, **options)
  select2 = if from
    find(:select2, from, options.merge(visible: false))
  else
    select = find(:option, value, options).ancestor(:css, 'select', visible: false)
    select.find(:xpath, XPath.next_sibling(:span)[XPath.attr(:class).contains_word('select2')][XPath.attr(:class).contains_word('select2-container')])
  end
  select2.click
  find(:select2_option, value).click
end
```

That should let you call `select_from_select2` just like you would call `select` and it will find the select2 widget associated with the given `<select>` element (hidden by select2) and choose the correct entry from it.

Comment: As a sidenote....should these still "auto" scroll into view on Firefox? or is that only a chrome thing? Also what does **options exactly do?

Comment: @msmith1114 They "should" however geckodriver/firefox isn't always as good about it since they seem to have been much more focused on the letter of the webdriver spec (and waiting until the spec is changed when it has a defect), while chromedriver/chrome appear more focused on making testing work.  If you find it not scrolling correctly due to multiple nested overflow elements etc, you can always add a manual scroll call into your helpers like `element.execute_script("this.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'instant', block: 'center', inline: 'center'}");`

Answer (score 0):

I had tested the Thomas´ answer but it doesn´t work for me. When Capybara click in the desired option, the select2 box close itself and set the 0 option. Finnaly, I made a walkaround as I check the option I want as selected and trigger the change.select2 event. I know that I dont really test the select2 box.

```
    def self.select2 (page, datos)

        page.execute_script("$('##{datos[:from]}').select2('open')")

        if page.find(".select2-results li", text: datos[:texto]).click

            page.execute_script("$('##{datos[:from]} option[value=\"#{datos[:valor]}\"]').prop('selected', true)")
            page.execute_script("$('##{datos[:from]}').trigger('change.select2')")
        end

        page.find(:css, '#' + datos[:from]).value
    end
```

As I keep my module Helper without include it in tests, I needed to include self in the name of the method and take 'page' from the capybara´test as parameter.
The variable 'datos' is a hash with the selector, the text of the option and its value.

As select2 box close when capybara click on it, I wrap the walkaround inside the if clause to be sure that some parts of the select2 box were working.

Finally, I returned the current value of the select to test it (really, it doesnt needed as I set the option with that value as 'selected')

I hope it would help anyone.